# Using GitHub project in Android Studio

Tags: android, github, dependencies

I know there are already similar question but I still could not find a way to do this:
I want to import and use the following GitHub project in my own Android Studio project:
https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button

The owner say in another topic to just add a dependecy:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.shamanland:fab:0.0.5'
}
```

I already tried:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

But it did not help. Could someone please explain how to add such GitHub projects the easiest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two gradle files..You should add dependancy in **inner** build.gradle file. In **outter** build.gradle file you should add repositories...

Comment: I am sorry, but I am a little confused. What exactly do I have to do step-by-step, do I have to download the github project and manually add it to my adroid project and then edit the gradle file of my project and thw two gradle files of the github project?

Comment: No, you DON'T have to download github project and manually add it to project. You just must make two steps. In first step you add `repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}` to build.gradle of your project. In second step you add `dependencies {
compile 'com.shamanland:fab:0.0.5'
}` to build.gradle of your module. Please see also http://rominirani.com/2014/08/19/gradle-tutorial-part-6-android-studio-gradle/